# C casting inside of structs from void *

Tags: c

I'm trying to cast a struct inside a struct but am running into issues, heres my simplified code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    void *test;

} abc;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} def;

int main()
{
    abc *mystruct = malloc(sizeof(abc) + sizeof(def));
    mystruct->(def *)test->a = 3;
    return 0;
}
```

the abc struct may have different types of structs in them, so I'd like to cast dynamically, however, this doesn't appear to work. How do I accomplish this in one statement?

Answer (score 1):

Split the allocation in two parts, first:

```
abc *mystruct = malloc( sizeof(abc) );
```

But, when you try to do( if test would be properly cast )

```
mystruct->test->a
```

`test` member isn't pointing anywhere, and by dereferencing it you get undefined behavior.
First point it to valid memory

```
mystruct->test = malloc( sizeof( def ) ) ;
```

Then you can use it:

```
( ( def *)mystruct->test )->a = 3;
^                        ^
```

Notice the parenthesis, you are casting the member void which is `mystruct->test` not just `test`.

Answer (score 1):

When casting from `void*` the proper way is to use `static_cast` in C++:

```
abc *mystruct = static_cast<abc*>(malloc(sizeof(abc)));
mystruct->test = malloc(sizeof(def));
static_cast<def*>(mystruct->test)->a = 3;
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e09563ff3b415e8c)

Now as far as it concerns C. First of, I prefer to define `init` and `finit` functions for my `struct`s:

```
struct abc*
abc_init(int sz) {
  struct abc *out = (abc*) malloc(sizeof(abc));
  out->test       = malloc(sz);
  return out;
}

void
abc_finit(struct abc *in) {
  if(in) {
    if(in->test) free(in->test);
    free(in);
  }
}
```

Notice that allocation of `struct abc` is done in two steps first the memory for `struct abc` and then for member `test`.

Now the casting is done like:

```
((def*)(mystruct->test))->a = 3;
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51770a57f981e0aa)

Comment: This is `c`, note the tag.

Answer (score 1):

More commonly you would use a `union` for this sort of thing:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    } def;
    /* ..other variants you might want */
} abc;

int main() {
    abc *mystruct = malloc(sizeof(abc));
    mystruct->def.a = 3;
    /* do stuff with it */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    void *test;

} abc;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} def;

int main()
{
    abc *mystruct = malloc( sizeof( abc ) );

    if ( mystruct )
    {
        mystruct->test = malloc( sizeof( def ) );
        if ( mystruct->test )
        {             
            ( ( def * )mystruct->test )->a = 3;
            printf( "%d\n", ( ( def * )mystruct->test )->a );
        }
    }

    if ( mystruct ) free ( mystruct->test );
    free( mystruct );

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
3
```

Answer (score -1):

(Corrected)  `((def *)mystruct->test)->a = 3;`

type cast operator has less precedence than -> operator
[Here is the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work: `error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
mystruct->((def *)test)->a = 3;`

Comment: Have you allocated memory for your "test" pointer?
Looks like it points to nowhere

Comment: my mistake.
((def *)mystruct->test)->a = 3;